# how to add picasso library in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, picasso

I am getting this error, please help me.

```
     Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Cannot evaluate module picasso-master : Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

Done so far :

```
1. download the picaso 

2.unzip the zip folder

 3.Under project section created  one directory called as lib and add the unzip file

4. In settings-gradle

    include ':app'
include ':libs:picasso-master'

   wrote these lines.

5. after that in project structure module dependency  add the picasso library


6. rebuild and clean
```

7.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile project(':library:picasso-master')
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
}
```

i add these lines in build gradle file too. but same error coming. what shall i do now. please help me.

Could you please tell me how I add picasso library?

Comment: Why don't you just add the `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
` gradle dependency to your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: please tell me how to add the picaso. i am new to android studio

Comment: Just add `dependencies { compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0' }` to your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @ dextor i have doubt...my picaso-master have no build-gradle.file. is it ok ? k i will add that line and check

Comment: You don't need to clone the repository at all.

Comment: i add that line but showing same error(i edited my post)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Add this to your dependencies in `build.gradle`:

[image]

```
dependencies {
 implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
  ...
```

The latest version can be found [here](https://github.com/square/picasso)

Make sure you are connected to the Internet. When you sync Gradle, all related files will be added to your project

Take a look at your libraries folder, the library you just added should be in there.

[image]

Comment: i add that line but showing same error(i edited my post)

Comment: Hmm.Try rebuilding the project.

Comment: yes. i rebuild it too,,, i dnt know what i done wrong

Comment: One more thing you could try, delete `include ':libs:picasso-master'` from your settings.gradle file,delete the file you created also and rebuild.Or if you are not far gone in your project, you can delete it and follow the new steps suggested to add a library project in build.gradle

Comment: sorry,,,could you please tell me what are the step by steps to add the library. ok I  will create new project too

Comment: The joy about using the method I and others gave you is that you don't have to go through any "steps" besides just copying and pasting `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'` in your build.gradle file and syncing your project.It's very simple.I advice you create a new project

Comment: sorry again,,,then no need to add picasso lib (what i download is)

Comment: Yes, once you add the code to your dependecies and sync, you automatically install picasso.You do not need to create a lib folder or copy anything else.

Comment: hey wow,,,, i created new project and add that  line  in build.gradle. now no errors. but how i know the picasso is added to my project.

Comment: Thank you ,,,,very much.  My project also have that structure... thank you once again

Comment: When i add in the gradle 
 compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

It didn't worked for me. May be latest version might not include all the classes.

Version 2.5.0 worked for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 23):

[image: easiest way to add dependence]

hope this help you
or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> => select Dependencies tab and find what you need ( see my image)

Comment: @ meow meo What tool are you using to make the video of screen and then convert it to good quality and reasonable sized .gif ? (nice idea)

Answer (score 10):

Add the Picasso library in Dependency

```
dependencies {
       ...
       implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
       ...
    }
```

Sync The Project 
Create one imageview in Layout

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</ImageView>
```

Add the Internet permission in Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

//Initialize ImageView

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

//Loading image from below url into imageView

```
Picasso.get()
   .load("YOUR IMAGE URL HERE")
   .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 4):

Dependency

```
dependencies {

   implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

}
```

//Java Code for Image Loading into imageView

```
Picasso.get().load(werURL).into(imageView);
```